# IIS Many to One Certificate without requiring SSL

Tags: ssl, iis, ssl-certificate

I am setting up a site in IIS 8.5, Windows Server 2012 R2.

The site needs to use Many to One certificates to verify clients.

My question is can you use a Many to One cert setup on a site that does not 'require' SSL (ie doesn't use SSL)?

I would have expected all users to see a 401 screen before their certs are setup but this is currently not the case. I am wondering if it is because I don't have SSL setup yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client certificate Authentication requires SSL and it is mandatory.The client certificate is sent when the [SSL handshake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security#Client-authenticated_TLS_handshake) happens .In IIS settings, If you select Require to require client certificates. Then, you must enable Require SSL as well.

As per [MSDN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753983(v=ws.10).aspx) ,

> If you want all clients to verify their identity, you must specify
>   that client certificates are required. If some clients can access
>   content without first verifying their identity, you must specify that
>   client certificates are accepted.

But whether you select Accept or require,SSL is mandatory.